# Display Sum of time in HH:MM format in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008

I have a table with last column with total_service_time in HH:MM format getting correctly from my SQL Query.

I am getting #Error while adding expression =Sum(Fields!total_service_time.Value) in last row to get the sum of total_service_time in HH:MM format.

Is there any way to get the Sum of time in HH:MM format in last row

My query for total_service_time value:

```
(SELECT    CAST(total / 60 AS varchar(8)) + ':' + CAST(total % 60 AS varchar(2)) AS Expr1
 FROM (SELECT CAST(SUM(Action.[Travel Time] + Action.[Total Productive Time]) AS int) AS total) AS T) AS total_service_time
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk5Bh.jpg)
Thanks,
Salman

Comment: Is total_service_time an int representing seconds? or is it a string with HH:MM format?.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta:it is varchar ,Please look at my query, "(SELECT    CAST(total / 60 AS varchar(8)) + ':' + CAST(total % 60 AS varchar(2)) AS Expr1
 FROM (SELECT CAST(SUM(Action.[Travel Time] + Action.[Total Productive Time]) AS int) AS total) AS T) AS total_service_time "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to sum up hours and minutes whose format is not compatible to with `SUM` so to add hours and minutes you need to use specific `DATETIME` functions.
Try out the below expression -

```
=Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(Fields!total_service_time.Value,2)), "<DataSetName>")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!total_service_time.Value,2)), "<DataSetName>") / 60),2)
  & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!total_service_time.Value,2)), "<DataSetName>") Mod 60
```

What I am trying is taking the total from the hours, adding the overflow from the total minutes, then concatenating the minutes.
References - 
[image: Sample DataSet]
[image: Output]

**Edit:**
New expression as per the requirement -

```
=SUM(Hour(Fields!total_service_time.Value)) + FLOOR(SUM(MINUTE(Fields!total_service_time.Value))/60) & ":" & SUM(MINUTE(Fields!total_service_time.Value)) Mod 60
```

Screenshots based on edited query - 
[image: Dataset Replicated]
[image: Result - as Output]

**Edit:**
Try this expression -

```
=Sum(CInt(MID(Fields!total_service_time.Value,1,INSTR(Fields!total_service_time.Value,":")-1)), "<DataSetName>")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!total_service_time.Value,2)), "<DataSetName>") / 60)
    & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!total_service_time.Value,2)), "<DataSetName>") Mod 60
```

Comment: it getting the Same error , This is my query (SELECT    CAST(total / 60 AS varchar(8)) + ':' + CAST(total % 60 AS varchar(2)) AS Expr1
 FROM (SELECT CAST(SUM(Action.[Travel Time] + Action.[Total Productive Time]) AS int) AS total) AS T) AS total_service_time

Comment: you are doing the formatting in database side or ssrs side?

Comment: database side , i am getting the result perfectly in ssrs table, need to get only the sum of those values in HH:mm format

Comment: @Sam - so in your ssrs - dataset you are having rows of 'total_service_time' in HH:MM format but datatype of `varchar` and you want to sum all of them in a separate row-column in HH:MM format?
Also could you post a screenshot with the data - it would be easier.

Comment: @Abhishek- same error. please look at the screenshot

Comment: @Sam - I tried using your query to populate the dataset and used the same query to calculate the addition - posted screenshots for the same too. Maybe I am missing something in between - how the data is populated and how the expression is been done

Comment: Result is perfect when the values in 2 digits like 99:99. if the values 3 digits like 101 , it getting error

Comment: @Sam - could you please give an example of three digits for an HH:MM format - how would the time be displayed in that case?

Comment: 75:40 &  25:30  and result should be 101:10

Comment: @Sam - updated the expression. but just a suggestion it's a very bad design to store HH:MM in 3 digit format. you should change the design to incorporate DD:MM:MM